# Switching between image and video in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to create Qt application, where will be possible to change view between video and images depends on called function. There is short example of my .qml file structure:

```
ApplicationWindow {
Rectangle {
    Rectangle {
        id: Container

        function dispImage(_title, _path)
        {
            //show imgae
        }
        function dispVideo(_title, _path)
        {
            //show video
        }
        Rectangle {
            id: titleContainer
            Text {
                id: title
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: image
            Image {
                id: image

            }
         }
         Rectangle {
            id: video
            Image {
                id: image

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which one mechanism should I use? Is this possible to do that by calling proper function from code?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to achieve that.

You can use a `Loader` and load a different `Component`, or you can simply hide one and show the other:

```
    function dispImage(_title, _path)
    {
        image.visible = true
        video.visible = false
        //...
    }
    function dispVideo(_title, _path)
    {
        image.visible = false
        video.visible = true
        //...
    }
```

However that code you have there isn't likely to work, seeing how you have the same `id: image` 3 times, you also have an id that begins with a capital letter, which is also "illegal" in QML. Maybe next time try posting working code to demonstrate some initial effort to accomplish your task.